# Nested dictionary out of grouped pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

> ```
>     Tail Number | flight route | digit
>     _______________
>     001C     | (VB, MI)   | 1
>              | (CC, SK)   | 2
>              | (KF, KC)   | 1
>     004N     | (AZ, AL)   | 2
>              | (AU, NY)   | 3
>     005F     | (ALB, TPA) | 5
>              | (ORD, JAC) | 2
> ```

the variables that i'm interested in are tail number, fligh route (a tuple) and digit (which is an integer value column).

i would like to make a nested dictionary out of it having tail number as key and an other inner dictionary where the key is flight route and value is digit. The nested dictionary ideally would look like this:

```
d = {001C :{  {(VB, MI): 1}, {(CC, SK): 2},  {(KF, KC):1} },
    004N :{    {(AZ, AL): 2}, {(AU, NY):3},
    005F :{  {(ALB, TPA):5},  {(ORD, JAC):2},  ... }
```

could you help me?

Comment: do you really need `d = {001C :{  {(VB, MI): 1}, {(CC, SK): 2},  {(KF, KC):1} }...`? will `d = {001C :{  (VB, MI): 1, (CC, SK): 2,  (KF, KC):1}...` be ok?

Comment: It would be great

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: Thank you but also thanks to Jim who suggested me to reset index first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is using `groupby` and dict comprehension

```
{k: dict(zip(v['flight route'], v['digit'])) for k, v in df.groupby('Tail Number')}

Out[209]:
{'001C': {('VB', 'MI'): 1, ('CC', 'SK'): 2, ('KF', 'KC'): 1},
 '004N': {('AZ', 'AL'): 2, ('AU', 'NY'): 3},
 '005F': {('ALB', 'TPA'): 5, ('ORD', 'JAC'): 2}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dict comprehension like this:

```
d = {i: {j:df.loc[(df['Tail Number']==i)&           
                  (df['flight route']==j),'digit'].iloc[0] #take every digit
           for j in df.loc[df['Tail Number']==i,'flight route']} #for every flight route
           for i in df['Tail Number']} #in each Tail Number
```

Two dict comprehensions which, like `for` loops, iterate over 1) Tail Number and 2) flight route (within each Tail Number).

```
Out[8]: 
{'001C': {('VB', 'MI'): 1, ('CC', 'SK'): 2, ('KF', 'CC'): 1},
 '004N': {('AZ', 'AL'): 2, ('AU', 'NY'): 3},
 '005F': {('ALB', 'TPA'): 5, ('ORD', 'JAC'): 2}}
```

If you have a multiindex you may need to first do

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

Comment: Thank you for suggesting me to reset index. Your answer is correct but the other one is shorter!